# Most efficient way to add a serial column to a huge table

Tags: postgresql, performance, update, sequence

What's the *fastest* way to add a BIGSERIAL column to a huge table (~3 Bil. rows, ~ 174Gb)?

EDIT:

- I want the column to be incremented values for existing rows (`NOT NULL`).
- I didn't set a fillfactor (which looks like a bad decision in retrospect).
- I don't have a problem with disk space, just want it to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD column bar bigserial;
```

Will be filled with unique values automatically (starting with 1).

If you want a number for every existing row, **every row in the table has to be updated**. Or do you not?

The table will be bloated to twice it's size if it cannot reuse dead tuples or free space on the data pages. Performance of the operation might benefit a lot from a [`FILLFACTOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) lower than 100 or just random dead tuples spread out over the table. Else you may want to run `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` afterwards to recover disk space. This won't be quick, though.

[**`pgstattuple`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstattuple.html)
You may be interested in this extension. It helps you gather statistics on your tables. To find out about dead tuples and free space:

Install extension once per databae:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgstattuple;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM pgstattuple('tbl');
```

#### Alternative

**If** you can afford to create a new table, which would break depending views, foreign keys, ...

Do it all in a single transaction, to skip writing WAL for the data inserted into a table that has been created in the same transaction. This saves *a lot* for populating a big table. But it requires `wal_level` set to `minimal`, which was the default up to Postgres 9.6. But the default changed to `replica` with **Postgres 10** to allow WAL archiving and replication by default. If you don't have nor need either, you can set that back to `minimal` for great savings. You need:

```
max_wal_senders = 0
wal_level = minimal
```

.. and then restart the server to take effect.
Read the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-WAL-LEVEL) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/populate.html#POPULATE-PITR). And [this blog post](https://postgrespro.com/blog/pgsql/5967974) for understanding.

```
-- start transaction 
BEGIN;

-- create empty copy of the old table - possibly add INCLUDING ... ①
CREATE TABLE new_tbl (LIKE old_tbl);

-- add the bigserial column ...
ALTER new_tbl ADD column bar bigserial;
-- ... **or** an IDENTITY column in Postgres 10 or later ②
ALTER new_tbl ADD column bar bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;

-- insert data from old table, automatically filling the new serial /IDENTITY
    
INSERT INTO new_tbl
SELECT *             -- new column filled with default
FROM   old_tbl
ORDER  BY something; -- or don't order if you don't care: faster

COMMIT;
```

① About `CREATE TABLE ... (LIKE ...)` with `INCLUDING` clause(s):

- [Copy table with separate sequences for serial columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91632/copy-table-with-separate-sequences-for-serial-columns/91658#91658)

(You may want to hold off costly features until *after* the table has been filled.)

② About `IDENTITY` columns:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860)

The new serial column is missing in the `SELECT` to the `INSERT` and will be [filled with its default value automatically](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html). You can spell out all columns and add `nextval()` to the `SELECT` list to the same effect.

Make sure you got all your data in the new table.
Add indexes, constraints, triggers etc. you had in the old table *now*.

```
DROP TABLE old_tbl;
ALTER TABLE new_tbl RENAME TO old_tbl;
```

Might be quite a bit faster overall. This leaves you with a vanilla table (and indexes) without any bloat.

You need free disk space - around the size of the old table, depending on the state of the table - as wiggle room. But you may need just as much with the first simple method because of table bloat. Again, details depend on the state of your table.

Comment: Wrap the alternative in a single transaction, that will be much faster. It will avoid additional `fsync`s

Comment: @FrankHeikens: That became less accessible with Postgres 10. I updated with details.