# Import using pgAdmin3 produces ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: postgresql, database-design, import, ddl, auto-increment

I am importing from the GUI a CSV file into a table. I have created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE jira_tickets.daqa_rpt_tbl
(
  daqa_report_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 'jira_tickets.daqa_id_seq'::regclass,
  project_name character varying(250) NOT NULL,
  jira_key character varying(250) NOT NULL,
  jira_summary text NOT NULL,
  issue_type character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  jira_status character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  jira_resolution character varying(250),
  jira_assignee character varying(250) NOT NULL,
  jira_reporter character varying(250) NOT NULL,
  jira_created text,
  jira_last_viewed text,
  jira_updated text,
  jira_resolved text,
  last_updated timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT "daqa_report_id_PK" PRIMARY KEY (daqa_report_id)
);
```

[image: Error Message]

When I import I get this error.  Clearly the sequence is not incrementing when I move to the next row. Here is how I declare the sequence:

```
  CREATE SEQUENCE jira_tickets.daqa_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 1000000000000000000
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE jira_tickets.daqa_id_seq
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE jira_tickets.daqa_id_seq TO public;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE jira_tickets.daqa_id_seq TO postgres;
```

Any suggestions or trouble shooting would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your CSV import supplies a value for the `daqa_report_id` then that won't increment the sequence. You need to manually adjust the sequence after such an import. Search for "setting sequence value in postgres"

Answer (score 1):

The column default for `daqa_report_id` would have to be:

```
nextval('jira_tickets.daqa_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Not:

```
'jira_tickets.daqa_id_seq'::regclass
```

That would just fetch the OID for the sequence object from `pg_class`, which is converted to a meaningless, static `bigint` number.

pgAdmin has nothing to do with this.

But just use the pseudo data type [**`bigserial`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) instead. It does everything automatically. Here's how you would add a `bigserial` to an existing table:
[Most efficient way to add a serial column to a huge table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20801/most-efficient-way-to-add-a-serial-column-to-a-huge-table/20802#20802)

Comment: Thank you!  Yep that did it. How I was importing the data was my only point for mentioning pgAdmin.